# How to create stripe standard account with flutter and firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, oauth, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have this amazing flutter app and I managed to set up a payment system with Stripe. My app is a marketplace so I have many vendors and I am able to collect money from the users and transfer the money to vendors. I have create a test vendor and it all works fine in testing mode. Now I would like to let prospective vendors to create a Stripe standard account and connect with my platform. Here are the instruction I would need to follow:  [link to stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts)

I read the instructions but I am not able to understand or implement it. I would like to know if I can implement the steps within my Flutter app or not. I am not familiar with servers but I have managed to use firebase to create charges. My first problem is the redirect URI (what is this?). The second problem is how to handle the response from stripe (step 3) and lastly get the vendor data with a POST request... Is there anything simple to use in flutter? I have seen [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth) and [this](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2) but I am not sure they can be used...

Can you please clarify what should I do here. Many many thanks in advance

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter oAuth : how to get started with OAuth and Stripe connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661232/flutter-oauth-how-to-get-started-with-oauth-and-stripe-connect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did

1. in firebase: I created an http function, ie `exports.createStripeAccount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res)`
2. in stripe: set that function as redirect uri
3. in flutter: `launch(url_to_connect_the_account)`
4. in firebase inside the httpfunction:

```
    return stripe.oauth.token({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: req.query.code,
    })
```

and that's all folks!

Comment: LaunchUrl opens a browser, using a webview and Deeplinks would be preferable-