# Flutter oAuth : how to get started with OAuth and Stripe connect

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe connect in my flutter app. Here are the [steps](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts) I need to implement. Can anyone please navigate me on how I could achieve this in Flutter?

I am able to create a button with the endpointUrl but that's all..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this myself using firebase cloud functions:

- first you create an https function in the firebase cloud function
- then you add the link created by the function to your stripe dashboard
- then you write the following logic to your function

  - obtain the the authorisation code
  - fetch data from stripe
  - save the response somewhere (in my case in realtime database)

Here is the function

```
exports.connectStripeStandardAccount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  let authCode = req.query.code;
  return stripe.oauth.token({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: authCode,
  }).then(async response => {

    await admin.database()
       .ref(`/accounts/${authCode}`)
       .set(response);
     return res.send("Well done, account integration is completed. You can now close the window and go back to the app");
  });
});
```

Comment: just to clarify, the url of this cloud function would be the redirect uri correct? After they finish registering their information will they automatically be brought back into the app or shown a screen prompting them to return to the app?

Comment: the latter I believe

Answer (score 0):

The answer selected is not completely correct:
If you dont assign the `account_id` to a user then it's of no use.
The only way to pass the `user_id` (fUser.uid) is to pass it using the state parameter.

```
exports.StripePI = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
//    console.log('accountIdq ' + req.query.error);
//    console.log('accountIdq ' + req.query.state);
//    return;
//        if(!req.query.code)
//            return res.send("An Error has occured please try again");
    const response = await stripe.oauth.token({
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: req.query.code,
    }).then(async response => {
            var connected_account_id = response.stripe_user_id;
          await admin.firestore().collection('Registration').doc(req.query.state)
                           .update({customer_id : connected_account_id});
           return res.send("Well done, account integration is completed. You can now close the window and go back to the app");
        });
});
```

Comment: Error: could not handle the request / the stripe connected account is created, but adding an entry to firestore didn t work, any idea ?

Comment: This code is updating an already present document, maybe thats the thing, and plus you must remember to pass the user_id in the state in query like I mentioned above

Comment: yes, I ve already updated the code to a set function, but how do you add the state parameter to this https ? https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={code}&scope=read_write

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an in-app stripe connect account registration with flutter you will need these:

1. A server or service to complete the OAuth like [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/overview/) or [Integromat](https://www.integromat.com/en/) (I used Integromat)
2. A link that will redirect to your app (I used Firebase Dynamic Link)

### STEPS TO CREATE THE REGISTRATION FLOW

**INTEGROMAT/FIREBASE FUNCTIONS SETUP**

I decided to use Integromat instead of Firebase Functions because is easier to set up, doesn't need any code, and decreases my server load.

If you want to create it on Firebase Functions you will need to have a [Blaze Plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)

If you don't know it, Integromat will automate processes that you currently handle manually, via webhooks. It is not only capable of connecting apps (like GoogleCloud, Facebook, AWS...) but can also transfer and transform data.

Create a new scenario and add a `Custom Webhook`. Click on it and click on `add`, name it, and save it. It will now create a custom link to your webhook.

Close and click on the semi-sphere next to the webhook, to add the new module.
Select HTTP and `Make a Request`.

In the URL section insert `https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token`.
Method `POST`.
Body Type `Application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Create now those fields :

Key `client_secret` - value *your stripe client secret* You can find it on your stripe dashboard. I advise you to first use the test mode and after that, change the value to the live key.

Key `grant_type` - value `authorization_code`

Key `code` - leave the value blank. We will add it later.

Save and close

For Firebase Functions you can create a new HTTPS function (I didn't test this)

```
var stripe = require("stripe")(*your stripe client secret*);

exports.connectStripeStandardAccount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{

  let authCode = req.query.code;
  return stripe.oauth.token({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: authCode,
  });
});
```

Remember to install stripe package `npm install stripe`

---

**STRIPE SETUP**

If you are in the test mode go to this [link](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/applications)
If you are in the live mode go to this [link](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/applications)

Go on the bottom and activate oAuth for standard accounts or for Express Account.

Click on `Add URI` and add the webhook link of Integromat that you created or the link related to your Firebase function.

If you used Firebase add this link `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/connectStripeStandardAccount`

For Integromat you will need to create the structure. To do this click on `Test OAuth`, copy the link, and open it in incognito mode. Open your Integromat scenario and click on your webhook. Now click on `Re-determine data structure`.

Return to your stripe registration page and click on `Ignore account form` at the top.

Return on Integromat and select the HTTPS request, modify the field `code`, and insert the variable code (will open a dialog with all queries from the webhook). Confirm and save.

Now click on the play button and reopen the stripe registration link in incognito mode and click on `Ignore account form`. Return in Integromat and add a JSON module after the HTTPS request. In the `JSON string` insert the `Data` variable and save. Create a `Webhook Response` module after the JSON module.

In the status put `301`, then click on Ok.

---

**DEEP LINK SETUP**

It's time to set up the redirect link that will return the user to our flutter app or on our website if the user hasn't it installed.

I used [Firebase Dynamic Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) You can follow [this](https://medium.com/dev-genius/firebase-flutter-dynamic-links-step-by-step-guide-630402ee729b) tutorial for set up.

Go to the dashboard and create a new Link prefix and a new dynamic link, remember to select to redirect your users to the right app.

Click on the three dots in your dynamic link row and click on `Link Details`. Copy the extended link.

Open Integromat and select the last module you created (Webhook Response). Click on `Show advanced settings` and on the Header add :

Key `Location` - value the extended dynamic link that you copied.

If you want your app to elaborate data from the stripe OAuth response you can modify the extended dynamic link by adding `?` on the link parameter: `link=https://test.page.link?stripe_user_id={{14.stripe_user_id}}`

And select the variable parsed from the JSON module. Remember to click on the save icon to save your scenario.

On Firebase Functions you can do this when the function `stripe.oauth.token` finish (I didn't test it):

```
res.setHeader('Location', your dynamic link);
res.status(301).send();
```

Remember to deploy it.

---

**FLUTTER APP SETUP**

The code here is very simple. To initialize the connect account registration you only need to set up a button that will launch the stripe connect URL. You can use `launch(url);`

You can find that URL [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#redirect-uri). Remember to be logged in to your stripe account to get the right *stripe client id*. You can easily get it in the same section you added the webhook link in your stripe connect settings.

Delete `&redirect_uri=https://sub2.example.com` on the URL.

Now you can test your app and will see that when you complete your stripe connect registration/login you will be redirected to your app.

If you want to have an in-app web view you can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

To handle the response, you need to have installed the package [`firebase_dynamic_links`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links)

Set your Main widget Stateful and on the `initState` run the method `getDynamic()` :

```
void getDynamic() {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink().then((value) {
      if (value != null) {
        _connect(value);
      }
    });

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(onSuccess: (value) async {
      if (value != null) {
        _connect(value);
      }
    }, onError: (error) async {
      debugPrint('DynamicLinks onError $error');
    });
  }

void _connect(value) {
    Uri deepLink = value.link;

    print("Link :" + deepLink.path);

    print("Query :" + deepLink.queryParameters.toString());

    String stripeUserId = deepLink.queryParameters["stripe_user_id"];
    
  }
```

You need to have both of them to handle dynamic links when your app is running and when it's closed.

Comment: hi, https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/connectStripeStandardAccount is not a valid URI ... ?

Comment: you need to replace <project-id> with your firebase project id

Comment: yeah no sorry it s just that I didnt deploy first ...

Comment: hello, instead of a deeplink, do you think it would be possible to user Webview javascript channel to trigger if the status changed (and therefore close the webview) ?

Comment: I don't think so. When the customer clicks on the connect button, he will be redirected to the page you set on stripe. You could try to redirect the customer to your website and retrieve the response with the webview. I tried this before utilizing the deep-link, but I didn't succed

Comment: if you don t specify any return url, and just send a message like so --- return res.send("done"); it will redirect you to a blank Html file with just a simple html body and this 'done' string. I though maybe we could monitor it ...

Comment: But I ve used Deeplinks (tks for the roadmap). Though I am actually implementing onboarding functions, instead of oAuth.

Comment: @MatteoAntolini Hi, I'm sort in the same situation but I have a few doubts as I didn't quite grasp the flow yet. Here you're all using `OAuth` API while in the guide  linked in the question( the Stripe guide to connect onboarding) they (`step 1`) create an `account`, (`step 2`) create an `accountLink` for it and send it to client. Then if I'm not wrong (`step 3`)  client app follow that link to complete the onboarding.  What's the difference with this flow and why you're all suggesting `OAuth` API ?

Comment: AlsoI'm just keeping Auth and Messaging + Goole Login and Storage as I'm moving away from Firebase. I'm running a Nodejs server so I'd like to use that instead of Firebase Functions or INTEGROMAT and `uni_links` package instead of Firebase dynamic link .

Comment: @Vincenzo Hi, the main difference is that with stripe connect onboarding, you must create a stripe standard account. With the oAuth method, clients can register or  log in with their stripe account and you can manage both standard and express accounts. `uni_links` should work

Comment: @MatteoAntolini Hi Matteo, I decided to go with the connect onboarding as  the majority of my sellers won't have a Stripe account ( they're not that into tech and my startup helps bringing it to them ) and for the ones that do have a Stripe account I've seen that they can login with it ( not tested it yet) in the onboarding process. I just check at login if they've completed the process and show reminders accordingly.

Comment: Also by creating an account myself I can better manage when creating a Standard or an Express account as you can specify what type of account you creating. Ideally I would want to use `Custom` and manage all the authentication and file provisioning in app to have a complete white label Stripe integration, but I could still use Stripe onboarding also with Custom account.
Many thanks for answering and happy new year.