# Flutter Stripe how to create Standard Connect account

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Just a simple question.

I have been looking around the web for support to create Standard connect account with Flutter but I am still running into the following issue:

\What should I put in my `return_url` field in my `stripe.accountLink.create()` method? According to the documentation it is the: `The URL that the user will be redirected to upon leaving or completing the linked flow.`

But it's a mobile app? So  I am a bit confused on what I should put there.

```
const accountLink = await stripe.accountLink.create({
    account: account['id'],
    type: 'account_oboarding',
    refresh_url: '', // Here I have my https onRequest method
    return_url: '', // <----- what should I put in here?
});
```

Comment: That doesn't look like flutter/dart code.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes you are correct. This is what I have in my cloud function for when a seller registered in my app. The reaon I have Flutter tag here is as what I am asking: If I am not a web service but a mobile app what should I put in the  return_url field ?

Comment: Cloud Functions code runs fully outside the context of the calling app.  For Flutter apps running on Android or iOS, I don't think that URL is going to be meaningful at all.

Comment: @DougStevenson I agree with you 100% on that. According to Stripe's documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links/create) that `return_url` is a required field, I am curious what others has done and/or worked around it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter oAuth : how to get started with OAuth and Stripe connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661232/flutter-oauth-how-to-get-started-with-oauth-and-stripe-connect)

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to use Flutter's [`uni_links`](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) for this, since I suspect you want them to come right back into your app.