# How do I get my flutter firebase user to also create their stripe account

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage, stripe-payments

I am creating a mobile marketplace however, I don't know how to allow my user who has created an account with firebase also create a stripe account and having that connect to my app so that when they create a listing for a product, they can receive money in their stripe accounts after someone buys their specific product.
My question is, does anyone know how I can do that? I tried following the stripe instructions but realized that they are only making an account and after they sell an item, they arn't getting payed. How would I program that? How would they get payed? For firebase functions, I am using Js. My mobile app is made using flutter and my backend is firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a payout system "add to each user a field which holds the total gained money and when this user collect a specific amount you can send money from stripe to his bank account" because it's not right to connect each user with Stripe as it or any other payment gateways allow to connect the app with one account and it requires some information to be able to receive money .. etc , you see that you put private key and other key to connect with stripe and those keys and you should hide'em with env properties so no one can see'em
I hope you got what i want to say

Answer (score 0):

Stripe Connect has a 3 different charge types to select from : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges

In general, you would either create the charge on your platform then transfer the funds to the connected account, or create a charge on the connected account. You would want to follow one of the two guides below depending on which charge type [0] you choose :

- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide
- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/enable-payment-acceptance-guide

Following the flows mentioned above, funds will accumulate in the connected account's balance and will be available to be paid out. You can read about connected account payouts in more detail here : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/bank-debit-card-payouts

You would probably want to write in to Stripe support if you need further guidance on how Stripe Connect works as a product.

Answer (score 0):

- This [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments) provides detailed steps on how you can
  process payments with Firebase using a stripe account.
- It walks you through customizing and deploying your own version of
  the open-source [cloud-functions-stripe-sample.web.app](https://cloud-functions-stripe-sample.web.app/) example
  app using stripe payments whose source code is available at this
  [GitHub link](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/stripe).
- Also have a look at this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661232/flutter-oauth-how-to-get-started-with-oauth-and-stripe-connect/65563096) where a
  stackoverflow user has shown how he has integrated Firebase with his
  stripe account using Firebase functions.
- For a detailed description on how you can create a stripe account for
  Firebase Flutter, go through [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-a-marketplace-in-your-flutter-app-and-accept-payments-using-stripe-and-firebase-72f3f7228625) article.